How to select entire Material-React-table group when using enableMultiRowSelection=false and enableGrouping=true?
How to select entire Material-React-table group when using enableMultiRowSelection=false and enableGrouping=true?
Currently, if group radio button is selected, only last item in group is selected
All items in group should be selected.
enter image description here
All items in group should be selected.
